# Firebase Auth: can't delete Firestore documents in promise returned from currentUser.delete()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using firebase authentication and angularfirestore in my app, and I came across a strange problem. I want to delete a user document in firestore after I delete the user in firebase auth as shown below, but the firestore portion doesnt work.

**Edit 2**: In the code, `this.currentUser` is not the same as `angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser`. It is a local variable I created separately.

```
return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.delete().then(() => {
            this.angularFirestore.collection("userData").doc(this.currentUser.email).delete().then(() => {
                this.currentUser = null;
                this.currentUserSubject$.next(this.currentUser);
                this.setAuthenticationDetails({authType: null, rememberMe: false});
                this.storageService.setRememberedUser(null);
            });
        })
```

However, if I were delete the document from firestore first, and delete the user from firebase auth afterwards, it works.

```
return this.angularFirestore.collection("userData").doc(this.currentUser.email).delete().then(() => {
            return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.delete().then(() => {
                this.currentUser = null;
                this.currentUserSubject$.next(this.currentUser);
                this.setAuthenticationDetails({authType: null, rememberMe: false});
                this.storageService.setRememberedUser(null);
            });
        })
```

Anyone knows why this is happening? They both return promises so i expected the behaviour to be the same.

**Edit 1**: added catch, but nothing's being printed

```
return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.delete().then(() => {
            return this.angularFirestore.collection("userData").doc(this.currentUser.email).delete().then(() => {
                this.currentUser = null;
                this.currentUserSubject$.next(this.currentUser);
                this.setAuthenticationDetails({authType: null, rememberMe: false});
                this.storageService.setRememberedUser(null);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

**Edit 3:** Security Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're observing makes sense to me.

If you have security rules set up on Firestore that require an authenticated user in order to delete the documents, it makes sense that the documents would fail to delete after removing the user account (as the user is not longer authenticated).  You will definitely want to do everything you can **while authenticated** before signing out or deleting the user account.

You should add error checking to your code to find out if anything went wrong with the document delete.  Right now, you don't have any `catch` callbacks on the promise chain, so you'd never know if something went wrong.  I suspect you'll see a "permission denied" type of error on the document delete due to security rules rejecting the request.

Comment: Hi, i added the catch callbacks, but in the console nothing is being printed (which is very strange, since I'd expect some error if the request is not going through?). Also, I don't have any security rules that require users to be authenticated

Comment: Even if you have not written security rules on your own, it might have security rules like below created on project creation. So be mindful about that.  Daruul makes perfect sense in his comment and we can not perform operation if user is not logged if security rules exits.  

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: My security rule allows for all operations so can't be that

Comment: Please edit the question to show your security rules.

Comment: added the rules

Comment: If you don't get some sort of result after a document write, then you should file a bug with angularfire with your specific steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happened is that after you do `auth.currentUser.delete()`,  `this.currentUser` also gets cleared (if it holds `auth.currentUser`)

So you are just deleting `doc("")` which didn't fail. But there is no such document, so you won't see anything.

Comment: Thats my bad, I didn't make it clear that this.currentUser is a local variable that isn't affected by auth.currentUser(). I've tested it with console.log and this.currentUser isn't null, hence why I asked this. Really confused